# Converting Tensorflow model to CoreML model. Shape Translator missing for OP Slice

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml, coremltools

Im using TFCoreml in python to convert my Tensorflow model into CoreML for development on an iOS device using the CoreML Libs.

Im using the following python code to try and convert the model to CoreML.

import tfcoreml as tf_converter

```
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb', 
                     mlmodel_path = 'ml_model.mlmodel', 
                     output_feature_names = ['SemanticPredictions:0'],
                      input_name_shape_dict =  {'ImageTensor:0' : [1, 512, 512, 3]})
```

This gives the following error:

> Shape Translator missing for OP of type Slice.

I read the docs a bit further for TFCoreml and it states that Slice isn't fully supported, and some custom conversion code is required for this to work. In the TFCoreml documentation it suggests breaking the frozen graph into sub graphs and converting them individually then merging them back together post conversion.

I updated my code to use custom layers, but I don't really understand how the custom conversion functions work.

Just need a few pointers on where to look to begin understanding how to write these custom conversion methods so I can solve my problem with converting the Tensorflow model to CoreML.

**[EDIT]**

I did some more reading into the TFCoreml examples and documentation and have adapted my solution to this.

```
import tfcoreml as tf_converter

def _convert_slice(**kwargs):
    tf_op = kwargs["op"]
    coreml_nn_builder = kwargs["nn_builder"]
    constant_inputs = kwargs["constant_inputs"]

    params = NeuralNetwork_pb2.CustomLayerParams()
    params.className = 'Slice'
    params.description = "Custom layer that corresponds to the slice TF op"
    # get the value of begin
    begin = constant_inputs.get(tf_op.inputs[1].name, [0,0,0,0])
    size = constant_inputs.get(tf_op.inputs[2].name, [0,0,0,0])
    # add begin and size as two repeated weight fields
    begin_as_weights = params.weights.add()
    begin_as_weights.floatValue.extend(map(float, begin))
    size_as_weights = params.weights.add()
    size_as_weights.floatValue.extend(map(float, size))
    coreml_nn_builder.add_custom(name=tf_op.name,
                                input_names=[tf_op.inputs[0].name],
                                output_names=[tf_op.outputs[0].name],
                                custom_proto_spec=params)

coreml_model = tfcoreml.convert(
        tf_model_path='frozen_inference_graph.pb',
        mlmodel_path='my_model.mlmodel',
        input_name_shape_dict={'ImageTensor:0':[1, 512, 512, 3]},
        output_feature_names=['SemanticPredictions:0'],
        add_custom_layers=True,
        custom_conversion_functions={'Slice': _convert_slice}) # dictionary has op name as the key

print("\n \n ML Model layers info: \n")
# inspect the CoreML model: this should be same as the one we got above
spec = coreml_model.get_spec()
_print_coreml_nn_layer_info(spec)
```

I'm still getting the same error as before

> Shape Translator missing for OP of type Slice.

But i did notice I'm also getting this error/warning

> custom_conversion_functions={'Slice': _convert_slice}) # dictionary has op name as the key

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Is this the DeepLab model? What version of tfcoreml are you using? You should be able to convert this just fine if you don't go all the way to `SemanticPredictions:0` but a few layers before that, such as `BilinearResize_3:0`.

Comment: Yeah this is the DeepLab mode, I have done additional training to tailor the model towards what I needed for the semantic seg. Any chance you could send me an example? Im pretty new to all this and still trying to understand how it all works

Comment: As it happens, I recently wrote a book with Core ML tips and tricks and the DeepLab model is one of the examples in the book. See my profile for the link.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I managed to convert the deeplab semantic segmentation model to CoreML, but the outputs it gives me are a bit strange. [Float 1 * 1 * 1 * 513 * 513 array], so giving me 5 shapes back with those float values, but i cant work out how to get the pixel values. Also I've had to implement a custom Slice layer, which i dont fully understand how to use, because it just gives me that same data, and no start/end index for the slicing of the input arrays. If you could give me some pointers on how to get this performing as expected. Also have you managed to convert this model before?

Comment: I've worked out now how to get the Slice start/end indexes. But unsure on what to do with them. I get two Range<Data.Index> one which is 0 ..< 12 and the other is 0 ..<16, i dont know which array(s) need slicing with that index.

Comment: You don't need the slice layer, it is not necessary for this model to work. Simply convert the model up to (but not including) that layer. As for the output, it is in the standard Core ML format for when the output shape is not known, which is (sequence length, batch size, channels, height, width). But since the first three dimensions are all 1, you can simply ignore them.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, how can i use TFCoreml to convert the model without using those layers? I understand that models are composed of multiple layers, but i dont quite get how i remove layers during the conversion process.

Comment: You need to tell tfcoreml what the output tensors are. Simply choose an output tensor _before_ that slice layer. You can use a tool such as Netron to inspect the graph to see what the tensors are.

Comment: Hi again Matthijs, so i've got the model converted, i used netron to visualise the model so i could work out which layer i need to convert to. When i run it using coreml everything runs fine, apart from i do get some strange results. I believe i need to adjust the RGB bias. Unless the way im converting the output into an image isnt working correctly. Just wondering if you have any thoughts. Also im going to look into buying your book seems like you have loads of info in this area, could be a good read and help me understand some more about CoreML.

Comment: The book goes into great detail on those kinds of issues. You can also check out my blog post on this topic: http://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/ But for DeepLabv3, I believe you don't need to use any preprocessing options since the TF model already does this inside the graph (unless you removed those operations).